# Deleted posts showing in the Earned Bounties list

Tags: support, bug, bounties, deleted-posts

Normally, one can only search their own deleted posts or they need a direct link to the deleted post. However, I've stumbled on a case where in the list of earned bounties on someone else's profile deleted questions *are* listed.

[Case in point link on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9640177/mayank-kumar-chaudhari?tab=bounties&sort=earned)

[image]

Is this supposed to be the case, or is this a bug?

Users with less than 10,000 reputation cannot see the deleted posts listed, but do see the combined rep total including that of the deleted posts. (Thanks αλεχολυτ for the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394881/deleted-posts-showing-in-the-earned-bounties-list#comment1320104_394881).)

Note that this doesn't seem to be a caching issue, as [a post deleted four years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52962181/5211833) is also showing up in the list. Nor is this a bug on a single profile, [this Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3840170/user3840170?tab=bounties&sort=earned) has the same issue.

Comment: It seems it is only visible for 10k+ rep users. Cause I see only 13 bounties, but the earned reputation is the same - 2525.

Comment: Most likely a bug, the source is that we should be seeing our own deleted posts with bounties in our own profile, and there's no check if we're viewing someone else profile.

Comment: do you have any answers on the deleted post? It might be checking if its visible at all to you - since if you answered you can always see the post

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no, I don't have any connection to those posts. No editing, voting, answering or even seeing them previously. Others (with 10k) at Stack Overflow have confirmed this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I also see it on SO, and got nothing to do with that answer.  Also, it's not visible anywhere else in the profile, this seem like a simple overlook in that specific location.